# Parametrization of 2x2 unitary matrix with eigenvalues $\{1,-1\}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, parametrization, unitary-matrices

I want to parametrize the set $\mathcal{U}_{1,-1}(2)$ of complex 2x2 unitary matrices with eigenvalues $\{1,-1\}$.

I know of [various parametrizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#2_%C3%97_2_unitary_matrix) for the set $\mathcal{U}(2)$ of complex 2x2 unitary matrices with arbitrary eigenvalues, and am looking for analogous parametrizations when the eigenvalues are $\{1,-1\}$.

---

#### My Ideas

I have already come up with two constructions for this, but they seem overly complicated (I hope they are correct at least):

1. Take any parametrization $U_{\theta}$ of $\mathcal{U}(2)$. Then, $M_{\theta} := U_{\theta} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} U_{\theta}^\dagger$ is a parametrization of $\mathcal{U}_{-1,1}(2)$.
2. Take a parametrization $v_{\theta}$ of a complex 2D vector with norm $1$ (which one?). Compute $w_{\theta}$ orthogonal to $v_{\theta}$ (by swapping coordinates and switching the sign of the first dimension). Then, $M_{\theta,\varphi}:=\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
   v_{\theta} & e^{i \pi \varphi} w_{\theta} 
   \end{array}\right]
   \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
   \left[ \begin{array}{cc} v_\theta^\dagger \\ \hline e^{-i \pi \varphi} w_{\theta}^\dagger \end{array} \right]$ is a parametrization of $\mathcal{U}_{-1,1}(2)$, where $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$.